# What's the `echo_summary` function in bash?

Tags: bash

What's the `echo_summary` function in bash?

In the [ironic/sourcecode](https://github.com/openstack/ironic/search?l=Shell&q=echo_summary&type=Code)

I searched the `echo_summary`, it seems a function, but in `bash` I can not use it directly.

Comment: ironic must have a dependency that defines it. Note that it can also be an alias or an executable.

Comment: Probably related to this: https://github.com/openstack/devstack/blob/c6a4c4547d5aedbd17fb3c38c5e9283602376e51/stack.sh#L451